# split-apply-combine R

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I have a data table with several columns.
Lets say

`Location` which may include `Los Angles`, etc.

`age_Group`, lets say `(young`, `child`, `teenager)`, etc.

`year = (2000, 2001, ..., 2015)`

`month = c(jan, ..., dec)` 
I would like to `group_by` them and see how many people has spent money
in some intervals, lets say I have intervals of `interval_1 = (1, 100)`, `(100, 1000)`, `...`, `interval_20=(1000, infinity)`

How shall I proceed? What should I do after the following?

```
data %>% group_by(location, age_Group, year, month)
```

sample:

```
location age_gp  year month   spending
LA       child   2000   1         102
LA       teen    2000   1         15
LA       teen    2000   10        9
NY       old     2000   11        1000
NY       old     2010   2         1000000
NY       teen    2020   3         10
```

desired output

```
LA, child, 2000, jan  interval_1
LA, child, 2000, feb  interval_20
...
NY  OLD    2015   Dec  interval_1
```

the last column has to be determined by adding the spending of all people belonging to the same city, age_croup, year, month.

Comment: So there should be 3 total intervals/bins? Why do you have `interval_20`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a new column (`spending_cat`) using, for example, the `cut` function. After you can add the new variable as a grouping variable and then you just need to count:

```
df <- data.frame(group = sample(letters[1:4], size = 1000, replace = T),
                 spending = rnorm(1000))

df %>% 
  mutate(spending_cat = cut(spending, breaks = c(-5:5))) %>%
  group_by(group, spending_cat) %>%
  summarise(n_people = n())

# A tibble: 26 x 3
# Groups:   group [?]
   group spending_cat n_people
   <fct> <fct>           <int>
 1 a     (-3,-2]             6
 2 a     (-2,-1]            36
 3 a     (-1,0]             83
 4 a     (0,1]              78
 5 a     (1,2]              23
 6 a     (2,3]              10
 7 b     (-4,-3]             1
 8 b     (-3,-2]             4
 9 b     (-2,-1]            40
10 b     (-1,0]             78
# … with 16 more rows
```